# Adding authentication header in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, urllib2, urllib

Using the urllib2 library and the add_header function, I am able to authenticate and retrieve data in python 2.7. But since urllib2 library in more present in python 3, how do I add the Basic Authentication header with urllib library?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [add_header](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.add_header) method of `urllib.request`'s Request class.

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('Referer', 'http://www.python.org/')
r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

By the way, I recommend you to check another way, using [HTTPBasicAuthHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#httpbasicauthhandler-objects):

```
import urllib.request
# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
                          uri='https://mahler:8092/site-updates.py',
                          user='klem',
                          passwd='kadidd!ehopper')
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

(taken from the same page)